# Why is it important to have more than one evaluation method for different machine learning algorithms?

Tags: machine-learning, evaluation

Couldn't find a precise and concise answer. I'm not particularly interested in different machine learning evaluation methods, I just want to know why it's important to have more than one?

Comment: Not a *programming* (or `r`) question, hence arguably off-topic here; you could try posting either at Cross Validated or at Data Science SE instead (notice only that cross-posting is [not allowed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each metrics gives a different insight and evaluates your model differently.
Let's take an example for binary classification:

- Accuracy tells you what percentage of your predictions are correct. But what if you also want to know exactly how many 1's you got wrong [i.e. you predicted 0's where they should be 1]. for this, you will calculate the recall score.

So you get the idea maybe you want good accuracy but also good recall [real world example : maybe spam detection], so you look at both metric and choose wisely

Comment: Thank you, the first sentence is what I was looking for!